# Scala match/case multiple typed branch

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

I will try to be as clear as possible.
I have this class that combines two other classes HBaseCREvent and HBaseCR:

```
class HBaseCREvent(val rowKey : scala.Predef.String, val actualEnd : scala.Predef.String, val actualImpact : scala.Predef.String, val actualStart : scala.Predef.String) 


class combinedType[T]
object combinedType {
  implicit object HBaseCREventWitness extends combinedType[HBaseCREvent]
  implicit object HBaseCRWitness extends combinedType[HBaseCR]
}
```

and I have a method to implement like this

```
def convertHBaseObj[T:combinedType](event: T) : CRInput = {
    event match {
      case t @ (_: HBaseCREvent | _: HBaseCR) => {
        this.setActualEnd(t.actualEnd)
        this.setActualImpact(t.actualImpact)
        this.setActualStart(t.actualStart)
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid repeating the same set of statements when the input is of type HBaseCREvent or HBaseCR.
However, this approach does not work. My IDE cannot resolve the attributes (t.actualEnd, t.actualImpact, etc).

I have also tried this:

```
def convertHBaseObj[T:combinedType](event: T) : CRInput = {
    event match {
      case t: HBaseCREvent|HBaseCR => {
        this.setActualEnd(t.actualEnd)
        this.setActualImpact(t.actualImpact)
        this.setActualStart(t.actualStart)
        }
      }
   }
```

but I got an error:

> illegal variable in pattern alternative

Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Define a function containing your statements and use two case statements. I am assuming the functions you call take an implicit argument of combinedType. BTW you should capitalise types, e.g. `CombinedType`

Comment: that approach does not work, you have to indicate which type of the combinedType you are using to operate over the attributes.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of setActualEnd, setActualImpact, setActualStart

Comment: Please also add the definitions of  setActualEnd etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of HBaseCREvent, HBaseCR then extract your methods into a trait and implement that.

```
trait MyTrait {
  def actualEnd = ???
  def actualImpact = ???
  def actualEnd = ???
}

def convertHBaseObj(t: MyTrait) = {
  setActualEnd(t.actualEnd)
  setActualImpact(t.actualImpact)
  setActualStart(t.actualStart)
}
```

If you don't have control then you could do something like the following. I am re-using CombinedEvent here because your version doesn't do anything.

```
trait CombinedType[T] {
  def actualEnd = ???
  def actualImpact = ???
  def actualEnd = ???
}

implicit def HBaseCREvent2CombinedType(t: HBaseCREvent) = new CombinedType[HBaseCREvent] {
  def actualEnd = t.actualEnd
  def actualImpact = t.actualImpact
  def actualEnd = t.actualEnd
}

implicit def HBaseCR2CombinedType(t: HBaseCR) = new CombinedType[HBaseCR] {
  def actualEnd = t.actualEnd
  def actualImpact = t.actualImpact
  def actualEnd = t.actualEnd
}

def convertHBaseObj[T](event: T)(implicit combinedEvent: CombinedEvent[T]) = {
  setActualEnd(combinedEvent.actualEnd)
  setActualImpact(combinedEvent.actualImpact)
  setActualStart(combinedEvent.actualStart)
}
```

Either solution is better than your pattern matching implementation because they will fail at compile time rather than at runtime if the wrong type is passed to convertHBaseObj

Comment: I answered in a new "answer"

Comment: Could you please just explain me how those implicit methods HBaseCREvent2CombinedType and HBaseCR2CombinedType work?

Comment: When you call `convertHBaseObj` with an argument of type `T` then the compiler will look for an implicit value of type `CombinedEvent[T]` (unless you explicitly pass the parameter). The compiler is clever enough to also look for implicit functions to build `CombinedEvent[T]` from an instance of `T`. In this case we have implicit defs to build `CombinedEvent` for `HBaseCREvent` and `HBaseCR` so we can call `convertHBaseObj` with an instance of either type.